# How to fix linkage error when using template class with static constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I have the following code

```c
#include <iostream>
template <class T>
class A
{
public:
    static constexpr int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
};

template<> constexpr int A<int>::arr[5];

int main()
{
    A<int> a;
    std::cout << a.arr[0] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation passes just fine but I have a linkage error which I don't understand

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test
/tmp/ccFL19bt.o: In function `main':
test01.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `A<int>::arr'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not just define it for one type, you need

```
template<class T> constexpr int A<T>::arr[5];
```

Comment: Suppose I have `typedef A<int> B;` in my header, is there a way I can use type `B` in order to allocate `arr` or do I have to use type `A`?

Comment: @e271p314 AFAIK you need to use `A`.